# How to change every file content in every subfolder using a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file

I searched a lot but I could not found a way to overwrite every file in every sub folder using a batch file.

I've found a way to delete these files and folders:

```
set folder="C:\test"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

but, I don't want to just delete, I want to change its content, like this:

```
echo whatever > song.mp3
```

Yes, I know this sounds a little weird, but can I make the second process using the that loop in the first code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /r "c:\test" %%i in (*) do echo whatever > "%%i"
```